# What is the best strategy to manage different screen resolutions in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

As I know, not all WP7 have 480 x 800 pixels in resolution.

What is the best strategy to manage different screen resolutions in Windows Phone 7 ??

If I hardcode the width, height, margin, etc. in the xaml, will it be messed when the phone does not support 480x800 resolution ??

Let's share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: I understand the question, but just to let you know, all the phones will have 480x800 at launch.

Comment: The story at the moment is the tools will offer ways to deal with this when there are multiple resolutions. For now this was not required for launch. I personally wouldn't invest time devising strategies until I see what faciliation is available. That doesn't mean you can't think about it as you go though and try to make choices that will make it easier later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have similar concerns around supporting smaller screens once they are available. When I asked Microsoft about it I got this response:

> Minimize setting heights and widths
>   directly. Use alignment, grids,
>   stackpanel, etc. to layout the UI. As
>   a test, you can create a desktop
>   Silverlight version / mock of the
>   project and test it in both
>   resolutions.

When I asked Brandon Watson last week he told me not to worry about it as they were working on some clever ways to handle this.

I know with XNA that there is scaling support built in, so in theory that makes handling different screen sizes in XNA easier but still leaves the issue of touch target sizes and the ratio differences in the 2 screen sizes. - I don't find letterboxing to be a good look ;)

With Silverlight the problems are potentially more complex as the following needs to be accounted for:

- Screen dimension ratio issues
- Making large text smaller so it
  doesn't take up a disproportionate
  amount of screen space.
- Not making smaller text smaller as it
  may become unreadable.
- Ensuring that controls which support
  gestures are still large enough to
  recognise the gesture.
- Ensuring that when neighbouring
  touchable controls are made smaller
  they still maintain sufficiently
  large touch targets that people can
  be confident about what they are
  touching.
- Making large images smaller so they
  aren't larger than the available
  space.
- Making sure that images aren't
  distorted when resized.
- and many more...

All that said, we'll just have to wait and see what Microsoft come up with and then adjust our apps accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using StaticResource.  These will change as the screen resolution and orientation change.  See [Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2010/06/Orientation-Strategies-for-Windows-Phone-7.html) or this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/egibson/windows-phone-7-jump-start-session-2-of-12-building-a-silverlight-application-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

You could also take advantage of relative control sizing using grids.

See Grid section under

[Object Positioning and Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189087%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You DO NOT care about screen resolution in Silverlight and you DO NOT use with/height or position in layout.

First thing is you dont really know what is resolution of device, because you are doing everying in resolution-independent units.

General rule is, when doing layout, you do it in such way, that content is able to layout itself acording to space it has available. StackPanel and Grid are HUGE help in this case. If resolution changes, you dont really have to do anything (if your UI is done right).

Handling different resolutions in XNA is probably same as in desktop games. Again, there is not much to do other than setting correct transformation matricies.