# Per Pixel Alignment

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is using Margins to align things where I want them a problem on Windows Phone 7? 
My alignment depends on resolution, font size etc. However, I am setting the font size, and all Windows Phone 7 phones have the same resolution. So is what I am doing a problem? Could the alignment breakdown on certain phones?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is the potential for issues (see [What is the best strategy to manage different screen resolutions in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020706/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-manage-different-screen-resolutions-in-windows-phone/4021924#4021924)), it's not something we can or should be too concerned about.

Previous plans for HVGA devices have been suspended but it's very likely we'll see different screen sizes or resolutions at some point in the future. At that point we'll likley have to worry about the consequences of setting margins or specific positions but until then either should be fine.

Note that use of Margins will make supporting both landscape and portrait orientations more easily. It will likley also make moving items within the visual tree easier without undue consequences.

Also be aware that you need to consider possibel issues when trying to get pixel perfect positioning of text (especially if it wraps) when that text is localized for different countries and/or languages.

Answer (score 0):

Now every WP7 devices have 800x480 resolution, but later on HVGA (320 x 480) devices will also be available.

Silverlight is very good at managing UI elements based on a style. If I were you I would use styles as much as possible - maybe I will port my app to desktop Silverlight or some new devices will be available.

Comment: This is more specific information. I have a Grid, which contains a Large TextBlock and a HyperLinkButton. I want the HyperLinkButton to be at the very end of the large amount of text. Imagine "For More info click here". The only way I could get it to work was to set the margins on the HyperLinkButton to make it line up perfectly, otherwise it is on a new line below the TextBlock. This method just seems like a terrible way.

Comment: Put TextBlock nad HyperLinkButton in another panel and then set the Margins and so on - it is not terrible ;). Or better you could make your own UserControl, new template for TextBlock with "Read more" feature ( actually try to google it f.e. http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/214687/509982.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to position things exactly then you might find it easier to use the `Canvas` element to contain your elements. You then use `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` to position each item relative to the top/left corner.

At the moment there is only one screen resolution to contend with, though this may change in the future, in which case using standard layout elements would be a better course of action.