# How to manage assets for different screen sizes - WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, assets, windows-8.1, screen-resolution

To manage different screen resolution, in windows 8, we put the different assets in folders named, scale-100, scale-140, scale-180.

For windows phone 8, how do we put different resolutions?  In the same folder? or different folders? If so how to name?

Could someone throw some light on this?

Comment: You can find detail answer on following post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020706/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-manage-different-screen-resolutions-in-windows-phon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather complex on Windows Phone 8.

Regarding the splash screen (if any), you can use special file names:

- SplashScreenImage.Screen-WVGA.jpg (for WVGA phones)
- SplashScreenImage.Screen-WXGA.jpg (for WXGA phones)
- SplashScreenImage.Screen-720p.jpg (for 720p phones)

For all other images, you have to implement an own class that returns the best image for the current resolution. This is explained in the following MSDN article: [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: What if we dont provide all the assets? Will supplied asset scale on its own?

Comment: You can return the same URI for different resolutions. If you do that, it will then scale on its own.